# ios sqlite insert data if not inserted before

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, insert, uibutton

in my view controller it shows full of detail. so when user click ADD button it will insert data into sqlite. Question is how to check if data is inserted before.

```
 //this code is in viewDidLoad
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM exhibitor"];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
     check= 0;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK){
        while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            char *exName2 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
            NSString *exNameStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:exName2];
            NSString *exhibName = [exhibitionArticle objectForKey:@"ex_name"];

            if([exNameStr isEqualToString:(exhibName)] ){
                check += 1;      
            }else{
                check += 0;
            }

        }
        NSLog(@"%d Result is", check);
    }     //this code checking my data is in sqlite or not
```

if data isn't in sqlite then button inserting data.

```
- (IBAction)addExhibitor:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"%d this is addExhibitor int", check);
    if(check == 0){
    NSDate *exhibAddDate = [NSDate date];
    NSString *exhibName = [exhibitionArticle objectForKey:@"ex_name"];
    NSString *exhibAbout = [exhibitionArticle objectForKey:@"ex_about"];
    NSString *exhibBooth = [exhibitionArticle objectForKey:@"ex_booth"];
    NSString *exhibAddress = [exhibitionArticle objectForKey:@"ex_address"];
    NSString *exhibTelephone = [exhibitionArticle objectForKey:@"ex_telephone"];
    NSString *exhibFax = [exhibitionArticle objectForKey:@"ex_fax"];
    NSString *exhibWebSite = [exhibitionArticle objectForKey:@"ex_website"];
    NSString *exhibEmail = [exhibitionArticle objectForKey:@"ex_email"];

    NSString *sql1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO exhibitor ('exhibAddDate', 'exhibName', 'exhibAbout', 'exhibBooth', 'exhibAddress', 'exhibTelephone', 'exhibFax', 'exhibWebSite', 'exhibEmail') VALUES('%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@')", exhibAddDate, exhibName, exhibAbout, exhibBooth, exhibAddress, exhibTelephone, exhibFax, exhibWebSite, exhibEmail ];

    char *err;
    if(sqlite3_exec(db, [sql1 UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK){

        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Could not update table");
    }else{

        NSLog(@"Table Updated");
    }
    }
    else{
     //   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Same Data" message:@"Your data already there" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
      //  [alert show];

    }


}
```

Comment: Why don't you just do a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM exhibitor WHERE ....` for that exhibitor (kind of like you demonstrated in your first snippet, but this time, add a `WHERE` clause) and if you get a non-zero value, you know it's there?

Comment: Unrelated, as an aside, rather than building your SQL with `stringWithFormat`, you should use `?` placeholders and then do `sqlite3_bind_...` commands. What's going to happen with your code if the exhibitor's name is `"Joe's Bar and Grill"`? Worse, your code can be subject to SQL injection attack, which is prevented if you use `sqlite3_bind_...` commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int check = 0;
sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
const char * sql;

sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM exhibitor WHERE exhibName = ?";

sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [[exhibitionArticle objectForKey:@"ex_name"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

    check = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);

}

sqlite3_finalize(statement);

if (check == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Result of count is %d and so the data is not in the database", check);
    //insert the data

    NSDate *exhibAddDate = [NSDate date];
    NSString *exhibName = [exhibitionArticle objectForKey:@"ex_name"];
    NSString *exhibAbout = [exhibitionArticle objectForKey:@"ex_about"];
    NSString *exhibBooth = [exhibitionArticle objectForKey:@"ex_booth"];
    NSString *exhibAddress = [exhibitionArticle objectForKey:@"ex_address"];
    NSString *exhibTelephone = [exhibitionArticle objectForKey:@"ex_telephone"];
    NSString *exhibFax = [exhibitionArticle objectForKey:@"ex_fax"];
    NSString *exhibWebSite = [exhibitionArticle objectForKey:@"ex_website"];
    NSString *exhibEmail = [exhibitionArticle objectForKey:@"ex_email"];

    sql = "INSERT INTO exhibitor ('exhibAddDate', 'exhibName', 'exhibAbout', 'exhibBooth', 'exhibAddress', 'exhibTelephone', 'exhibFax', 'exhibWebSite', 'exhibEmail') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [exhibAddDate UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [exhibName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [exhibAbout UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [exhibBooth UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [exhibAddress UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 6, [exhibTelephone UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 7, [exhibFax UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 8, [exhibWebSite UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 9, [exhibEmail UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE){
         NSLog(@"Exhibit added");
    } else {
         NSLog( @"Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2. Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }

} else {
    NSLog(@"Result of count is %d and so the data is already in the database", check);
}

sqlite3_finalize(statement);
sqlite3_close(db);
```

Try something like this!

--> exhibName <-- in the sql must be the column where you want to search for the data.

Best is to put this all in the IBAction you have.. And if check == 0,  perform the insert.

And please take a look at binding variables because you are vulnerable to sql injection. This means that if I type something like: "blabla; DELETE * FROM exhibitor; blabla" as the title for instance, you run the risk of users deleting all data in the table! Binding variables makes sure this doesn't happen.

Don't have XCode around, so I can't check if it all works.. Otherwise fiddle around till you have it!

Good luck

Comment: i really appreciate this code, this code works just fine for me. thank you Ron so much